# Run Flash in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, flash, xaml

i am trying to run a `.swf` file in my WPF application, i have created a `html` page and in that i have referenced my `.swf` file using `object` tag and then loading that `html` page in my `Main Window`

my xaml looks like

```
<Window x:Class="sirajflash.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser Name="myBrowser"></WebBrowser>
        <!--<Frame Name="myframe"/>--> //tried with frame also but no luck
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

assigning the source

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myBrowser.Source = new Uri(CreateAbsolutePathTo("playflash.htm"), UriKind.Absolute);
        }
        private static string CreateAbsolutePathTo(string mediaFile)
        {
            return System.IO.Path.Combine(new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName, mediaFile);
        }
    }
```

**The Problem:**

when i run the application the warning occurs that `ActiveX` content is trying to access etc etc and when i allow it nothing appears in my main window the warning keeps on occuring multiple times.

if i run the flash movie in the browser directly it runs just fine.

Regards.

Comment: Are you on x86 or x64 machine?

Comment: @spender any sugeestions i can find a way out

Comment: Its strange! I can load a local htm file from my C:\ hosting a local embedded swf file in a WPF `WebBrowser` control. I too got the warning at first but once I select "Allow Blocked Content" it works for me then on.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider adding the "mark of the web" to the hosted page: http://flash.fincanon.com/archives/162 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @AngelWPF can you upload your sample project somwhere form where i can download and see what i am missing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I have a flash based clock as a .swf file on my C:\Test\MyClock.swf
2. I have a htm file at C:\Test\MyHtml.htm

   ```
     <embed src=C:\Test\MyClock.swf
            width=200 height=200
            wmode=transparent type=application/x-shockwave-flash>
     </embed>
   ```
3. I have web browser control as below...

   ```
   <Window x:Class="MyFlashApp.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Grid>
       <WebBrowser Source="C:\Test\MyHtml.htm"></WebBrowser>
     </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
4. On running the app, I see the webbrowser control giving warning as **`"To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options."`**
5. I accept the warning by right click and the left click "Allow Blocked Content". A confirmation popup appears to which I say `Yes`.
6. I see the Flash based clock.

Comment: thanks alot that worked i was doing it with the `<object scr="example.swf"></object>` changing it to `embed` solved the problem

Comment: Glad i could help. This suggests another point that we must post as much relevant source code as possible with our question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser control can support flash directly . If you don't need to present anything in HTML then you can directly provide the path to the flash file .

```
myWebBrowser.Source  = "C:\Test\MyClock.swf"
```

However you will still get the IE warning message.