# Open flash document in web browser form embedded resource

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to open an .swf file from my embedded resources into the micorosoft web browser component but the page comes up blank (plain white).

```
wb.Navigate("res:\\" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\testusb.exe\\DS4.swf");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Flash in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607427/run-flash-in-wpf)

Comment: even if I load a file to memory stream it still turns out blank                                 FileStream file = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Lance\\Desktop\\DS4.swf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
           
            wb.DocumentStream = file;

Comment: I looked at that question. the solution didn't help. It is still blank