# How play swf file in wpf

Tags: wpf, flash, shockwave

I want to play a swf file in my wpf application
I google it and find this link
http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-play-swf-in-wpf-application/
but when I add Shockwave Flash Object 
I face this error 
"the following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in active designer"
also I read this link
[Run Flash in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607427/run-flash-in-wpf)
but my problem is when I play it in WebBrowser background is not transparent
(I want import a logo with transparent background to my project )
in the end how can I import swf file to my wpf project with transparent background
thnx

Comment: There/This is no error. What is your **actual** problem?

Comment: when I ok it Shockwave Flash Object dose not add to my toolbox

Comment: You have to add it manually as you can see from the code sample from the link you have. I think you can add a windows forms container but not the actual child at design time. You have to do this manually later.